# 4.4.2 SDCard directories - help

Tags: sd-card, storage, mount

have Samsung s5, rooted.
I need your help to understand something..
Here is my directories related to storage SDCard

```
/sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy (SymLink)
/mnt/extSdCard -> /storage/extSdCard (Symlink)
/mnt/sdcard -> /storage/emulated/legacy (Symlink)
/storage/sdcard0 -> /storage/emulated/legacy (Symlink)
/storage/extSdCard mounted to the SD-Card
/storage/emulated/legacy mounted to the internal storage
/storage/emulated/0 mounted to the internal storage
```

So only /storage/extSdCard is the real sdcard.

It is not seems to be right.. how can Applications know where to write to?
For example, Whatsup cannot find the SD for some reason - I believe it related to this issue..

what do you think of it?

Comment: If you cannot find it for some reason, it could be due to not being mounted. For example, in non-root you have it, but when doing `su` you loose it. Then you have to do `su -mm`, when using SuperSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications don't have to care *where* the storage is. They just ask the Android system to give them a "pointer" to it. There are specific API calls for this, like `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. For details, you might check on our sister site: [Get the right external storage from Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793906/get-the-right-external-storage-from-android-devices).

Comment: Take shart for example, sniffer tool, try to write to /sdcard..